# Audio Player in HTML 5 not working properly in chrome.(Forward & Rewind play)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, html5-audio

I am having problem in running HTML5 audio player in chrome.It is working fine in IE 9+ and Firefox. I have written javascript functions for forwarding and rewinding audio player on F7 & F8 key press,its woring fine in IE and FF but for some reasons its not working in Chrome.Following is the code.

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 118) { rewindAudio(); return false; }
    else if (e.keyCode == 119) { forwardAudio(); return false; }
} 

  // Rewinds the audio file by 30 seconds.        
    function rewindAudio() {            

        // Check for audio element support.
        if (window.HTMLAudioElement)
            {
               try {
                      var oAudio = audioPlayerInFocus[0]; 
                      oAudio.currentTime -= 1.0;
                }
               catch (e) {
                   // Fail silently but show in F12 developer tools console
                   if (window.console && console.error("Error:" + e));
                }
            }
      }

// Fast forwards the audio file by 1 seconds.
function forwardAudio() {

    // Check for audio element support.
    if (window.HTMLAudioElement) {
        try {
            var oAudio = audioPlayerInFocus[0
            oAudio.currentTime += 1.0;
        }
        catch (e) {
            // Fail silently but show in F12 developer tools console
            if (window.console && console.error("Error:" + e));
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect the currentTime is not changing in chrome.Is there any syntax mistake or browser related issue?please help me.thank you.

Comment: `var oAudio = audioPlayerInFocus[0` is a syntax mystake. Moreover, please tell us what is `audioPlayerInFocus`

Answer (score 0):

The following code works in all browser I have tested for me - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/florestan06/KF2jY/):

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="sample/one.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('keydown',function(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 82) { 
    console.log('r key = rewind');
    rewindAudio();
}
else if(e.keyCode == 70){
    console.log('f key = forward');
    forwardAudio();
}
});

function rewindAudio() {            
    console.log('rewindAudio');
    oAudio = $('audio')[0];
    oAudio.currentTime -= 1.0;   
}
function forwardAudio() {            
    console.log('forwardAudio');
    oAudio = $('audio')[0];
    oAudio.currentTime += 1.0;   
}
</script>
```

I have read people having specific design with the [F7 key](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/828400).

On a side note to detect HTML5 audio support I normally use functions like described in [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/everything.html).

Comment: Thanks for help,but still not working...I debugged the code in Chrome...The currentTime is getting changed but its not reflecting in Audio player in page....

Comment: I think you should provide an actual fiddle to your issue so we can try and reproduce what you are experiencing.